# What is the probablity the y value produced in a linear regression is correct?

Tags: regression, inference, linear, prediction-interval

Apologies in advance if I am using the wrong terminology. Is the y value produced by a linear regression model assumed to be the mean of a normal distribution? Meaning there is a 50% chance the actual value is greater than and 50% chance the number is less than the y value. What is the probability the actual y value is 1 standard deviation or greater than the mean?